# Hibernate one to many cascade save null pointer exception

Tags: hibernate, nullpointerexception, save, one-to-many, cascade

I have One to many relations as stated in the below two classes

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="version_mst")
    public class Version {

    private Long   id;
    private String versionName;
    private String releaseName;
    private Set<VersionReleaseComponents> versionReleaseComponents; 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    public Long  getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long  id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="versionName")
    public String getVersionName() {
        return versionName;
    }
    public void setVersionName(String versionName) {
        this.versionName = versionName;
    }

    @Column(name="releaseName")
    public String getReleaseName() {
        return releaseName;
    }
    public void setReleaseName(String releaseName) {
        this.releaseName = releaseName;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="version",cascade = { javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL },fetch = FetchType.EAGER,targetEntity=VersionReleaseComponents.class)
    public Set<VersionReleaseComponents> getVersionReleaseComponents() {
        return versionReleaseComponents;
    }
    public void setVersionReleaseComponents(
            Set<VersionReleaseComponents> versionReleaseComponents) {
        this.versionReleaseComponents = versionReleaseComponents;
    }

      }
```

One Version has many VersionReleaseComponents

```
     @Entity
     @Table(name="version_release_components")
     public class VersionReleaseComponents {

    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "versionId")
    private Long versionId;
    public Long getVersionId() {
        return versionId;
    }
    public void setVersionId(Long versionId) {
        this.versionId = versionId;
    }
    private Version version;
    private String componentName;
    private String versionNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="versionId", referencedColumnName="id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Version getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    public void setVersion(Version version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Column(name="componentName")
    public String getComponentName() {
        return componentName;
    }
    public void setComponentName(String componentName) {
        this.componentName = componentName;
    }

    @Column(name="versionNumber")
    public String getVersionNumber() {
        return versionNumber;
    }
    public void setVersionNumber(String versionNumber) {
        this.versionNumber = versionNumber;
    }

        }
```

When I try to execute the following

```
        Version v = new Version();
        v.setReleaseName("RN1");
        v.setVersionName("VName1");

        VersionReleaseComponents vrc = new VersionReleaseComponents();
        vrc.setComponentName("cn1");
        vrc.setVersionNumber("VNum1");
        vrc.setVersion(v);

        v.getVersionReleaseComponents().add(vrc); // null pointer error on here
        session.saveOrUpdate(v);
```

I get a null pointer exception on getting the set.Please guide me.

Create queries are as follows

```
      CREATE TABLE `version_mst` (
      `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `versionName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `releaseName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `last_modified_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
      UNIQUE KEY `VERSION_MAPPING_MST_UNIQUE` (`versionName`,`releaseName`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    CREATE TABLE `version_release_components` (
      `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `versionId` int(10) NOT NULL ,
      `componentName` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `versionNumber` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `last_modified_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
      CONSTRAINT `FK_VERSION` FOREIGN KEY (`versionId`) REFERENCES `version_mst` (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `VERSION_RELEASE_UNIQUE` (`componentName`,`versionNumber`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB   DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 2):

In `Version` you haven't instantiated the:

```
private Set<VersionReleaseComponents> versionReleaseComponents;
```

So you are adding `VersionReleaseComponents` to an uninitialized `Set`

to fix, set this:

```
private Set<VersionReleaseComponents> versionReleaseComponents = new HashSet<VersionReleaseComponents>();
```

or whatever `Set` you need

Comment: So where do I create a new instance? like                         <i>    vrc.setVersion(v);
  Set<VersionReleaseComponents> vset = new HashSet<VersionReleaseComponents>();
  vset.add(vrc);   v.setVersionReleaseComponents(vset); </i>

Comment: @user1393563 see edit in response. If this answers your question: please upvote and accept the answer...

Comment: On trying my above comment I get org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.abc.dm.dao.entities.VersionReleaseComponents]
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:94)
 at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)

Comment: @user1393563 I think it's caused by inserable=false

Comment: Making insertable = true, updatable = true gives the error Error connecting to the database org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.abc.dm.dao.entities.VersionReleaseComponents column: versionId (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: @nixsix6 You have defined column versionId 2 times...Once as a joinColumn, and once as the column name of the Long versionId. Rename one of these 2 with another name

Comment: versionId in VersionReleaseComponents is a foreign key for id(primary) in Version table

Comment: yes, but the name of the joinColumn does not need to be the same as the propertyname or as the name as the primary key in your Version class. it's just a name... name it as you like, the foreign key relation is determinded by the return type of your getMethod

Comment: On renaming to @JoinColumn(name="versionReleaseComponents", referencedColumnName="id", insertable = false, updatable = false) getting org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.abc.dm.dao.entities.VersionReleaseComponents]
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:94)
 at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)

Comment: because insertable=false... you can't insert if insertable is false. just remove it...

Comment: On changing to  @JoinColumn(name="versionReleaseComponents", referencedColumnName="id")
 again getting org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.abc.dm.dao.entities.VersionReleaseComponents]
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
 at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because you haven't initialize the `Set` variable. Initialize it in constructor or in field declaration.

When I run your code, I got the same exception, then it works after I initialized the variable into:

```
private Set<VersionReleaseComponents> versionReleaseComponents = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="versionId", referencedColumnName="id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Version getVersion() {
  return version;
}
```

for this:

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="versionReleaseComponents")
   public Version getVersion() {
      return version;
    }
```

and use the recomendation of @user1393563:

```
private Set<VersionReleaseComponents> versionReleaseComponents = new HashSet<VersionReleaseComponents>();
```

Regards.

Comment: I get, org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:  could not insert: [com.abc.dm.dao.entities.VersionReleaseComponents]
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
 at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)

Comment: Replace  @OneToMany(mappedBy="version"... for this: @OneToMany(mappedBy="id").

Comment: On changing to @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name="versionReleaseComponents", referencedColumnName="id") and  @OneToMany(mappedBy="id",cascade = { javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL },fetch = FetchType.EAGER,targetEntity=VersionReleaseComponents.class)
 getting error org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.abc.dm.dao.entities.VersionReleaseComponents]
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
 at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)

Comment: You can see this tutorial: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/.

Comment: Fix this: @JoinColumn(name="versionReleaseComponents") and @OneToMany(mappedBy="id"). Before add the properties if run.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the following:
Removed the declaration in VersionReleaseComponents

```
     @Column(name = "versionId")
    private Long versionId;
    public Long getVersionId() {
        return versionId;
    }
    public void setVersionId(Long versionId) {
        this.versionId = versionId;
    }
```

Changed VersionReleaseComponents declaration to

```
 @JoinColumn(name="versionId")
```

and Version declaration is

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="id",cascade = { javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL },fetch =  FetchType.LAZY)
```

The above changes worked.
I have changed to FetchType.LAZY for some other reason though it is not part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to add an item to Set which is NULL.

try this :

```
    Version v = new Version();
    v.setReleaseName("RN1");
    v.setVersionName("VName1");

    VersionReleaseComponents vrc = new VersionReleaseComponents();
    vrc.setComponentName("cn1");
    vrc.setVersionNumber("VNum1");
    vrc.setVersion(v);

    Set<VersionReleaseComponents> vrcs = new HashSet<VersionReleaseComponents>();
    vrcs.add(vrc);
    v.setVersionReleaseComponents(vrcs);

    session.saveOrUpdate(v);
```